# Sending JSON through requests module and catching it using bottle.py and cherrypy

Tags: python, json, cherrypy, bottle, python-requests

I have a server which needs to be able to accept JSON and then process it and then send JSON back. The code at my server side is using **bottle.py with cherrypy**. The route in concern is the following:

```
@route ('/tagTweets', method='POST')
def tagTweets():

    response.content_type = 'application/json'

    # here I need to be able to parse JSON send along in this request.
```

For requesting this page and testing the functionality, I'm using **requests** module code:

The data that I have to send is list of tweets. The data is itself fetched from some server which returns list of tweets. For fetching tweets, I'm using `requests.get` and then using json method of response object. This is working fine. Now I after some processing on this, I have to send this json, just like I fetched to another server.

```
url     = "http://localhost:8080/tagTweets"
data    = {'sender': 'Alice', 'receiver': 'Bob', 'message': 'We did it!'}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
r       = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

I'm not able to figure out how to gain access to the json send along the request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a `application/json` POST, simply access [`request.json`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.json):

```
@route ('/tagTweets', method='POST')
def tagTweets():
     response.content_type = 'application/json'
     sender = request.json['sender']
     receiver = request.json['receiver']
     message = request.json['message']
```

Comment: Dear Martijn, I'm using cherrypy with bottle.py. The server running command is like this :

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8082, server='cherrypy')

request.json is coming out as NONE for some reason

Comment: @VaidAbhishek: CherryPy is just another WSGI server in this case; what version of Bottle are you using? What does `request.body.read()` give you?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try...

//cherrypy

```
import json

@route ('/tagTweets', method='POST')
def tagTweets(UpdatedData=None):
    Data = json.loads(UpdatedData)
```

//javascript

```
function SendJson()
{
    var JSONObject = { changes: [] };
    JSONObject.changes.push({"sender": "Alice", "receiver": "Bob" }
            );

    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    else// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST","/tagTweets", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(JSONObject));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Andrew

Comment: Just a variable name.  Can be anything.  Oh - didn't add it to the cherrypy handler... I'll edit my answer right now.

Comment: If You're using POST then why are you sending data in query string !

Comment: Ah - thanks for your comment.  I've read up a bit more on XMLHttpRequest and updated my answer accordingly.