# CherryPy: What would the html command line syntax be if you wanted to pass a dictionary as an argument?

Tags: python, cherrypy

So I built a simple cherrypy function called 'echo' to try and figure out what cherrypy sends to my python function. Example:

```
http://djotjog.com/cp/echo/692-gg_org_id-2013-02-05.json/
RETURNS:
{'kw': {}, 'args': (), 'param_1': '692-gg_org_id-2013-02-05.json', 'param_2': None}
```

Now, this may seem weird, but I would like to pass a dictionary. Is this a html nightmare to do? Example:

this function needs two arguments. the params are optional:

```
def some_function(filename, params = {'db':'bh-localhost','h':'sparse','branching':7})
```

sending through cherrypy...

```
http://djotjog.com/cp/echo/692-gg_org_id-2013-02-05.json/{h:'branchy','branching':7,'db':'bh-localhost'}
RETURNS    
{'kw': {}, 'args': (), 'param_1': '692-gg_org_id-2013-02-05.json', 'param_2': "{h:'branchy','branching':7,'db':'bh-localhost'}"}
```

But when I pass through through the actual function and not the echo, it tells me:

404 Not found. Nothing matches the given URI.

Is this because the dictionary is a string and not a dict now? What trick can I do to pass a dictionary? Or just keep this to individual arguments?

Comment: I guess the flexibility I am aiming for here is a way to pass or omit any of a set of a dozen optional parameters without being picky about the ORDER that these parameters appears in the arguments list. What's the best trick for that?

Comment: Why you want url like `http://djotjog.com/cp/echo/692-gg_org_id-2013-02-05.json/{h:'branchy','branching':7,'db':'bh-localhost'}` and not standart format like `http://djotjog.com/cp/echo/692-gg_org_id-2013-02-05.json/?h=branchy&branching=7&db=bh-localhost`?

Comment: A json or dictionary format can have omitted keys and can be sent in any order, so it is less prone to errors. Otherwise, sending all the pieces to the function would work in that format too, but I have to be more intentional about optional vs required parameters with every call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting echo to receive a variable number of parameters...

```
@cherrypy.expose
def echo(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return kwargs['param_1']
```

Hope this helps.

Andrew

Comment: Will that also work for passing a variable number of arguments within a dictionary to a python function? Or must I convert such a string back into a dictionary within the function first?

Comment: I would pass the dictionary as a json object.  check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895084/sending-json-through-requests-module-and-catching-it-using-bottle-py-and-cherryp/14895178#14895178

Comment: So in my context, xmlhttp.open("POST","/tagTweets?UpdatedData=" + JSON.stringify(JSONObject), true); would instead be xmlhttp.open("POST","/cp/echo/params=" + JSON.stringify(JSONObject), true); if params was the dictionary I wanted to pass into the python function?

Comment: You're headed in the right direction.  now just define JSSONObject.  var JSONObject = { params: [] };
    JSONObject.changes.push({"param_1": "692-gg_org_id-2013-02-05.json", "param_2": "{h:'branchy','branching':7,'db':'bh-localhost'}" }
            );