# Python Bottle: Accessing array variable inside request POST data

Tags: javascript, python, request, bottle

I was recently handed a partially-completed project and I'm new to using Bottle. I have a situation where I'm sending a dictionary inside an AJAX request and Bottle is on the server side. The dictionary looks something like this (in JavaScript):

```
var myInt = 5;
var myArray = [0, 1, 2];
var data = {
    myInt: myInt,
    myArray: myArray
};
```

Then, in Python, I want to read in this data. I can't seem to get the array. I can get the int just fine. I've tried several things, but here's what made most sense to me that still didn't work:

```
try:
    myInt = int(request.forms.get('myInt'))
    myArray = request.forms.getall('myArray')
```

This results in an empty list for myArray. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've read every similar question on StackOverflow to no avail.

I know I could turn this into a string separated by pipes or something, but I would like to see if arrays are possible to send like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `request.json`:

```
try:
    myInt = request.json['myInt']
    myArray = request.json['myArray']
```

(Assumes your client is setting `content-type` to `application/json`.)

Here's a nice [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14895178/593047).

Comment: Thanks a ton! I'm learning a few too many new things at the same time...I don't yet understand what all I can do with the "request" in bottle, and then what I SHOULD do with it...but this worked :) Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Happy it helped!  I do also want to point out that the implementation of `request.json` parses the whole body each time it's called, so I'd recommend calling it just once and then pulling out any attributes you need.  I'll update the answer, too.

Comment: Scratch that--I just checked more closely and I think it does cache the parsed value, so no worries.  Proceed!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is the only problem, but (I think) you may be confusing JSON arrays and the use of `getall`.  You should use `get`, not `getall`, here:

```
myArray = request.params.get('myArray')
```

If I understand the code correctly, `getall` is for the case when you have multiple args with the same name, as in `http://example.com/get?foo=1&foo=2`.

On the other hand, your `myArray` variable is just a single reference to an array.

Hope this helps (even if it doesn't solve your problem).

Answer (score 0):

```
var myInt = 5;
var myArray = [0, 1, 2];
var data = {
    myInt: myInt,
    myArray: JSON.stringify(myArray)
};
```

Use `JSON.stringify` in js and in bottle `json_loads()`:

```
myInt = request.params.get('myInt')
myArray =  json_loads(request.params.get('myArray'))
```